# Is there any way to fix the header to not scroll with the enter of the softkeyboard in a activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a activity with a header on the top and a EditText below. When I am texting and press enter on the keyboard, the screen scroll down and hide the header. Is there any way to fix the header or, when press enter on the keyboard, not to scroll down the screen?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"        
tools:context=".ComentariosActivity" >


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:background="@drawable/background_40_blue"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:background="@drawable/navigation_bar"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivButtonOkComentarios"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/mini_button_ok" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="#FFCC66"
            android:textSize="48sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvRedeConfirmar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="Faça um comentário sobre a sua avaliação"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/borda_tabela" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etComentarios"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|top"                
            android:maxLength="500"                 
            >               

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="bottom" >

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivRodapeComentarios"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/rodape_tappa" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layout code here

Comment: maybe it has to do with the android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" parameter of activity in the manifest, if I understand you correctly

Comment: There are a lot of options here- http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html see if something helped you from there

Comment: In the manifest is  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateaweysvisible"